# Is this $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{\zeta(s)}=1$ ,for $s\to1$ ?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

let $s$ be a complex variable in the neighborhood of $1$, some calcualtion in [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28n%5E%28zeta%280.98%29%29,+n%3D1+to+infty) show that the series is convergent but this not convince me i want to know how do i show the bellow result if it is true ?

> > **Question:**
> >     Is this :$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{\zeta(s)}=1$ ,for $s\to1$ ?

Comment: Are you considering the limit as $s\to 1^+$ or $s\to 1^-$? It is relevant since the $\zeta$ function has a simple pole at $s=1$, so $\zeta(s)\approx\frac{1}{s-1}$ in a neighbourhood of $s=1$.

Comment: The series is divergent. Maybe you mean $-\zeta(s)$?

Comment: @Aforest: the limit as $s\to 1^-$ really is $1$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It should be $\frac{1}{s-1}$

Comment: @Aforest look in wolfram alpha for s=0.98 the sum diverge when i take - \zeta(s) in the exponent

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You're right. But for $s\to 1^+$ we should take $-\zeta(s)$.

Comment: Actually you only need the observation that $\lim_{s \to \infty} \zeta(s) = 1$ and that for $s < 1$ close enough to $1$ the sum is given by $\zeta(-\zeta(s))$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serie is not convergent. just try approaching from the right and you will get it totally unbound, so plug $1.0000001$ in wolfram to check it.

The phases of $\zeta(s)$ at the pole depend where you are coming from. From the left it tends to $-\infty$ and that is why it looked convergent.